# Latex: How to avoid omitting the author's name when citing two references with the same name author in the same position

Tags: reference, latex, bibliography

I cite 2 references via `\citep{liu2007cast,liu2011shadow}` command, and it style (after compiled) is:

```
In [Liu et al., 2011, 2007], the lower intensity rule is used as a preclassier in their method.
```

But my desired style is:

```
In [Liu et al. 2011, Liu et al. 2007], the lower intensity rule is used as a preclassier in their method.
```

As shown in the ref.bib, the names of the two authors are not exactly the same. But the author of the second reference was omitted by default.

sample of my book.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[semicolon,square,sort&compress,sectionbib]{natbib}
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{section}-\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{section}-\arabic{figure}}
\title{In nature}
\author{Null}
\date{}

\begin{document}
In \citep{liu2007cast,liu2011shadow}, the lower intensity rule is used as a preclassifier in their method. 
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

sample of my ref.bib

```
@inproceedings{liu2007cast,
  title={Cast shadow removal combining local and global features},
  author={Liu, Zhou and Huang, Kaiqi and Tan, Tieniu and Wang, Liangsheng},
  booktitle={2007 IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition},
  pages={1--8},
  year={2007},
  organization={IEEE}
}
@article{liu2011shadow,
  title={Shadow detection in remotely sensed images based on self-adaptive feature selection},
  author={Liu, Jiahang and Fang, Tao and Li, Deren},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on Geoscience and Remote Sensing},
  volume={49},
  number={12},
  pages={5092--5103},
  year={2011},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `\citep*` macro:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[semicolon,square,sectionbib,sort&compress,mcite]{natbib}
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{section}-\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{section}-\arabic{figure}}
\title{In nature}
\author{Null}
\date{}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{liu2007cast,
  title={Cast shadow removal combining local and global features},
  author={Liu, Zhou and Huang, Kaiqi and Tan, Tieniu and Wang, Liangsheng},
  booktitle={2007 IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition},
  pages={1--8},
  year={2007},
  organization={IEEE}
}
@article{liu2011shadow,
  title={Shadow detection in remotely sensed images based on self-adaptive feature selection},
  author={Liu, Jiahang and Fang, Tao and Li, Deren},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on Geoscience and Remote Sensing},
  volume={49},
  number={12},
  pages={5092--5103},
  year={2011},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
In \citep*{liu2007cast,liu2011shadow}, the lower intensity rule is used as a preclassifier in their method. 
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]